# No consigo conectarme a SQL Server desde C++

Tags: sql-server, c++, visual-studio

Estoy realizando una aplicación de consola en la que registro productos en una BD y sobre el día de ayer estuve realizando la conexión desde Visual Studio 2022 a la BD que tengo en SQL Server y no hay manera pese a que tenga bien el nombre del servidor (el cual es el nombre de equipo\SQLEXPRESS) y el puerto que en este caso es 1433, el que suele usar por defecto el programa.

```
void comprobarConexion(){

#define SQL_RESULT_LEN 240
#define SQL_RETURN_CODE_LEN 1000

//define handles and variables

SQLHANDLE sqlConnHandle;
SQLHANDLE sqlStmtHandle;
SQLHANDLE sqlEnvHandle;
SQLWCHAR* cadena;
SQLWCHAR retconstring[SQL_RETURN_CODE_LEN];

//initializations
sqlConnHandle = NULL;
sqlStmtHandle = NULL;
//allocations
if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlEnvHandle))
   goto COMPLETED;

if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlEnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, 
(SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
   goto COMPLETED;
if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlEnvHandle, &sqlConnHandle))
   goto COMPLETED;

//output
    cout << "Attempting connection to SQL Server...";
    cout << "\n";
//connect to SQL Server  
//I am using a trusted connection and port 14808
//it does not matter if you are using default or named instance
//just make sure you define the server name and the port
//You have the option to use a username/password instead of a trusted connection
//but is more secure to use a trusted connection

cadena = (SQLWCHAR*) L"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-STUDIO\\SQLEXPRESS,1433;DATABASE=productos;Trusted=true;";

switch (SQLDriverConnect(sqlConnHandle,
        NULL,
        cadena,
        SQL_NTS,
        retconstring,
        1024,
        NULL,
        SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)) {

    case SQL_SUCCESS:
        cout << "Successfully connected to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        break;

    case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
        cout << "Successfully connected to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        break;

    case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
        cout << "Could not connect to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        goto COMPLETED;

    case SQL_ERROR:
        cout << "Could not connect to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        goto COMPLETED;

    default:
        break;
    }

    //if there is a problem connecting then exit application
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlConnHandle, &sqlStmtHandle))
        goto COMPLETED;
    //output
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Executing T-SQL query...";
    cout << "\n";
    //if there is a problem executing the query then exit application
    //else display query result
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)L"SELECT @@VERSION", SQL_NTS)) {
        cout << "Error querying SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        goto COMPLETED;
    }
    else {
        //declare output variable and pointer
        SQLCHAR sqlVersion[SQL_RESULT_LEN];
        SQLINTEGER ptrSqlVersion;
        while (SQLFetch(sqlStmtHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS) {
            SQLGetData(sqlStmtHandle, 1, SQL_CHAR, sqlVersion, SQL_RESULT_LEN, (SQLLEN*) &ptrSqlVersion);
            //display query result
            cout << "\nQuery Result:\n\n";
            cout << sqlVersion << endl;
        }
    }
    //close connection and free resources
COMPLETED:
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlStmtHandle);
    SQLDisconnect(sqlConnHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlConnHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlEnvHandle);
    //pause the console window - exit when key is pressed
    cout << "\nPress any key to exit...";
    getchar();
}
```

Tenía un error que rápido solucioné que fue que no tenía el doble slash ("//") en el nombre del servidor y no se mostraba correctamente, pensaba que fallaba por eso pero sigue sin hacer la conexión.

Modifiqué el código a:

```
 //Variables temporales
string nombre, descripcion;
int stock;
float precio;
Producto prod = Producto("","",0,0.0);

SQLHANDLE sqlenvhandle;
SQLHANDLE sqlconnectionhandle = 0;
SQLHANDLE sqlstatementhandle = 0;
SQLRETURN retcode;
SQLWCHAR* cadenaConexion;

do
{
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlenvhandle))
        break;

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlenvhandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
        break;

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlenvhandle, &sqlconnectionhandle))
        break;

    SQLWCHAR retconstring[1024];
    cadenaConexion = (SQLWCHAR*)L"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-STUDIO\\SQLEXPRESS, 1433;DATABASE=productos;Trusted=true;";
    switch (SQLDriverConnect(
        sqlconnectionhandle,
        NULL,
        cadenaConexion,
        SQL_NTS, 
        retconstring, 
        1024, 
        NULL, 
        SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT))
    {
    case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
        break;
    case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
    case SQL_ERROR:
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
        retcode = -1;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (retcode == -1)
        break;

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlconnectionhandle, &sqlstatementhandle))
        break;

} while (FALSE);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle);
SQLDisconnect(sqlconnectionhandle);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlenvhandle);
```

Empleo la autentificación de Windows por lo que no tengo usuario ni contraseña y coloco `Trusted=true`.

```
cadenaConexion = (SQLWCHAR*)L"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-STUDIO\\SQLEXPRESS, 1433;DATABASE=productos;Trusted=true;"
```

Ahora mismo tengo el error

> SQLSTATE: 08001, The driver was unable to establish a connection with the data source.

Como datos adicionales tengo SQL Server 2019 Express instalado en el equipo y Visual Studio 2022 Community.

A continuación subo unas capturas de cómo tengo la configuración y los errores que da el programa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acabo de conectarme pero desde el entorno de Visual Studio y ahí si que la hace... no entiendo porque desde ahí si y desde el código no...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora tras aplicar la recomendación de @alfabravo me sale esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por último, acabo de ver que se el programa se mete por el caso del switch de "SUCCESS..." por lo que me está funcionando!

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135117/discussion-on-question-by-daburanet1998-no-consigo-conectarme-a-sql-server-desde).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi C++ está muy oxidado, pero puedo decir que esa cadena de conexión está rara. La [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/driver-specific-connection-information?view=sql-server-ver15) dice

```
DSN={MyDataSourceName};UID={MyUserID};PWD={MyServerPassword};UIDDBMS={MyDBMSUserID};PWDDBMS={MyDBMSUserPassword};
```

excepto cuando se tiene Trusted_connection, que sería algo como

```
Driver={SQL Server};Server=192.168.1.1\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=productos;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Si se usa el puerto por defecto, no hay que ponerlo (y tampoco debería ir con coma hasta donde recuerdo).

Comment: A ver Dios te oiga jeje voy a probar esa cadena y ya te digo...

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta que ahora parece que el programa me falla por otro lado, ya que me dice que la variable retCode no esta inicializada, la inicialicé con un 0 y me sale esto... pasó de darme SQL_STATE el error 08001 al 01000

Comment: Me funciona! Muchas gracias @Alfabravo, llevaba desde la semana pasada peleando con este problema, saludos y ahí tienes tu +1!

Comment: ¡Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeh! me alegra que funcionara! <:o)